# Kaplan Meier using survfit confidence interval of the median

Tags: r, confidence-interval, survival, kaplan-meier

In R, I am trying to produce a survival analysis using Kaplan Meier. I have previously used SPSS. I am trying to compare my results but R is producing a 95% confidence level of the median, whereas SPSS provides a 95% confidence interval.

How can I produce a 95% of the median provided by R? Here is a copy of my code:

```
survival.model <- survfit( Surv(Time, Outcome) ~1,
                           type = "kaplan-meier",
                           data = my_data,
                           conf.type = "plain",
                           conf.int=0.95)
survival.model
```

I understand that producing a summary of the model gives 95% CI's for each time point but I would like one for the median output above.

Any advice or support would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: One complication that any solution may need to address is that you need to take into account the uncertainty of the whole KM estimate, not just the uncertainty at a single time point.  I believe this requires one to get a simultaneous 0.95 confidence band instead of pointwise confidence intervals.  Simultaneous bands are slightly wider, and I don't know if this has been worked on for KM.  In other settings a simultaneous 0.95 band can be roughly approximated with 0.99 individual confidence intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Klein and Moeschberger](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953991) note (page 120, 2nd edition), with $X$ the survival time and $\hat x_p$ the estimate of its $p^{th}$ quantile ($p=1/2$ for median):

> In practice, the standard error of $\hat x_p$ is difficult to compute because it requires an estimate of the density function of $X$ at $\hat x_p$.

According the the "KM Analysis" section of the [SPSS Statistical Algorithms document](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSLVMB_28.0.0/pdf/IBM_SPSS_Statistics_Algorithms.pdf), SPSS uses what Klein and Moeschberger (Practical Note 3, page 122) call "an estimator of the large sample variance" of $\hat x_p$ via "a crude estimate" of the density function for $X$  "based on a uniform kernel density estimate." For the median CI, SPSS uses values based on the estimated $55^{th}$ and $45^{th}$ percentiles. That might lead to questions about how much confidence you should put in the SPSS confidence intervals in the first place.

That's not how estimates are done with the `survival` package. The standard method for median confidence upper and lower limits used with `survfit()` (via its associated `print()` or `quantile()` functions) is to return the times at which the pointwise confidence limits hit 50%, however those pointwise limits were specified in the original `survfit` object.*

As Frank Harrell notes in a comment, those confidence estimates based on pointwise survival estimates over time have a potential problem in that they don't represent simultaneous 95% coverage over the entire survival function. Several methods for Kaplan-Meier pointwise and simultaneous confidence intervals are referenced and implemented in the R [`km.ci` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=km.ci). Its `km.ci()` function can return a `survfit` object with adjusted simultaneous CI (the `logep` confidence band is recommended) that you could then interrogate with `quantile()`. For estimating CI around the median you *might* not need to use the full-curve 95% CI but use the function's `tl` and `tu` time-boundary limits to restrict attention to times around the median, although I haven't thought that through carefully.

---

*Your choice of `conf.type = "plain"` is generally not wise. See [Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842), page 16: "Several authors have examined the choices with somewhat different conclusions. The one certain and common thread in the reports is the marked inferiority of the plain scale: it results in intervals that may extend below 0 or above 1, and has poor coverage properties."